# sass-lint in Atom throws 'Unexpected Parse Error'

Tags: sass, atom-editor, gulp-sass, scss-lint

I have several simple `.scss` (SAAS) files and for each one I get a `sass-lint` error.

> Unexpected Parse Error

To the best of my knowledge, I have the most current [sass-lint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-sass-lint) plugin for Atom. It doesn't seem to affect anything and is more of a annoyance, however I would also love to know if I am doing something incorrectly.

Example code that generates the error:

```
$primaryFont: 'Lora';
$secondaryFont: 'Roboto';
$primaryHeader: 'Montserrat';
```

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Don't worry it's not you it's sass-lint!*

It is because you are indenting with spaces, there is a [bug](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/issues/560) in one of sass-lint's dependencies that causes `Unexpected parse error in file` to be logged when you indent with tabs rather than spaces.  It looks like they are planning to have it resolved in the next release, at which point the maintainer of the Atom plugin will need to update the dependencies of the Atom Package and publish a new version.

I figured this out by taking a look at the [`package.json`](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-sass-lint/blob/master/package.json) for [sass-lint](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-sass-lint) and specifically at the dependencies on `line 21`, there is a direct dependency upon the [`sass-lint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-lint) NPM package.  From there you can go back to the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint) which has all of the issues including [#560](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/issues/560) which describes the exact issue you are experiencing.

I have created [GitHub Issue on the sass-lint Atom Package](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-sass-lint/issues/70) for this, it is externally blocked by [Issue #62 on sasstools/sass-lint](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/issues/62), i.e. the NPM package, which was updated a couple of days ago by Dan Purdy who stated:

> We're at a bit of a crossroads at the moment, while running through our tests on all platforms we've found the latest version of the AST fixes a lot of our issues but also breaks a few things. Specifically Sass format on windows mainly. There's also some pretty annoying windows bugs left over so we're currently debating and looking into what our best course of action is. I hope to have 1.6 out soon though... I just can't say when.

Comment: FYI.  This appears to be fixed.   I am curious though... my scss file had no indentations, or spaces.   It was the top of the file.  As a matter of composition, should Sass be indented?

Comment: As far as I am aware it's customary to indent `.scss` files but like `.css` it's not required.

Comment: Thanks.   I'll find an example somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try validating your `.sass-lint.yml` here [online YAML lint tool](http://www.yamllint.com/)